# Error when converting spark df to pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I am trying to convert spark df to pandas df as:

```
pandas_df = spark_df.select("*").toPandas()
```

but I am getting the below error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

I also tried this way:

```
pandas_df = spark_df.toPandas()
```

but this also gives the same above error.

Adding the complete code here:

```
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sc.stop()

conf = SparkConf() \
    .setAll([('spark.executor.memory', EXECUTOR_MEMORY), 
             ('spark.executor.cores', EXECUTOR_CORES),
             ('spark.driver.memory', DRIVER_MEMORY), 
             ('spark.app.name', APP_NAME), 
             ('spark.cores.max', MAX_CORES),
             ('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions', 2001),
             # ('spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes', 268435456),
             # 
 ('spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold','52428800'),
             ('spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold',-1),
             ('spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled', 'true'),
             ('spark.local.dir', spark_local_folder)
            ])
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)



 spark_df = =sqlContext.read.format("parquet").\
   option("header","true").load(filename)

pandas_df = spark_df.select("*").toPandas()
```

Comment: Which version of PySpark you are using?

Comment: 2.4.5 @SuyogShimpi

Comment: Please, try by executing following statement `spark_df.toPandas()`.  [Visit for more](https://github.com/Evergreenies/data_engineering_pyspark/blob/main/pyspark_scripts/sales_analysis.ipynb)

Comment: I have already executed this command and this is also showing the same error.

Comment: Can you provide the rest of your code?

Comment: Hi @RobertKossendey, I have added the full code above.

Comment: Does spark_df.show() work?

Comment: Yes, spark_df.show() is working.